# target <html> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

trying to target the `<html>` tag with jQuery, below is my code:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function()
{
    $.post('/path/to/window.php', {id: $(this).data('id')}, function(res)
    {
        var newWindow = window.open('', 'NEWWINDOW1', 'height=700, width=500');
        $(newWindow.document.body).html(res);
    });
});
```

which is great, only problem is, res = `<html>` from top to finish, so my head element from res is being skipped because head can't exist in the body (well it can, it just won't work). I tried changing .body to .html but to no avail :( any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: this looks like it could have been solved by adding `target="_blank"` to a `<form>` element.

Comment: I didn't understand this phrase: "so my head element from res is being skipped because head can't exist in the body". You mean you got the whole html and header tag isn't included ?

Comment: @Hodrobond to use res as the document html

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Because res is <html><head>etc. etc. its appending to body, so my css is being missed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create a window with a page sending post data you can do it using a form submit using target window:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function()
{
    //create a window
    var newWindow = window.open('', 'NEWWINDOW1', 'height=700, width=500');

    //create a form with target NEWWINDOW1 and post 
    $('<form method="post" action="path/to/window.php" target="NEWWINDOW1">
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+$(this).data('id')+'">
   </form>').submit();
}
```

**EDIT:** Another way is using document.write

```
$('.btn').on('click', function()
{
    $.post('/path/to/window.php', {id: $(this).data('id')}, function(res)
    {
        var newWindow = window.open('', 'NEWWINDOW1', 'height=700, width=500');
        newWindow.document.write(res);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$(newWindow.document.body).html(res);` into `$(newWindow.document.body.parentElement).html(res);`. Since the `html` element will be the parent of the `body`, that should work.

Also, looking only at your question, it looks like no JavaScript is needed at all. It might be enough to simply have a [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) with [`target="_blank"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target) on it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you'll have to split the `head` from the `body`:

```
var newWindow = window.open('', 'NEWWINDOW1', 'height=700, width=500');
$(newWindow.document.body).html('<a class="foo">asdf</a>')
$(newWindow.document.head).html('<style>.foo{color:blue}</style>')
```